# Getting Access token using Oauth2 with standalone java application

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-drive-android-api, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to use Google drive's APIs to develop a standalone java application(using only java SE). For that I need to get access token using Oauth2.0.For getting the access token I have written following code:

```
    package Drive;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import static Drive.Constants.*;
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String url=OAuth2URL+"redirect_uri=https://localhost/"+"&"+"client_id="+CLIENTID+"&"+"scope="+SCOPE+"&"+
                    "access_type=offline&"+"response_type=code";

            System.out.println("URL is :"+url);
            HttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            if(response.getEntity().getContent()!=null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String str = null;
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I have put my credentials and oauth2.0 url in constant strings.My question is how
can I get the response of this API call in to my application? Do I need to fork a
listening process on specific port to get the response?

Answer (score 2):

The `redirect_uri` should be registered on the google console (in the place you get your `client_id`), and you should expose this url as a real http/s endpoint.

For more info see Step 2 Here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Hi @Gal Thanks for your help.  But  I couldn't find redirect_uri in oauth2 credential page.

Comment: Choose `Web Application` and see `Authorized redirect URIs` Here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient